# Sympy intersection of FiniteSets with strings

Tags: python, set, sympy, set-theory

Define two sympy `FiniteSet` sets `a` and `b` with each of them containing only one string element:

```
a = FiniteSet('red')
b = FiniteSet('yellow')
```

If I ask for the Intersection of those sets:

```
Intersection(a,b)
```

I was expecting to get as result an empty set `{}`, but I just get `Intersection({red}, {yellow})`.
Why is that?

It works well for Union:

```
Union(a,b) = {'red', 'yellow'}.
```

Even if I define those sets:

```
a = FiniteSet('red', 'yellow')
b = FiniteSet('red')
```

I get the expected result: `Intersection(a,b) = {'red'}`.

I was planing to use those set manipulations to reduce/simplify rather long symbolic representations of combinations of different sets. But with this behavior it will not work.

It also works well with the built-in python sets:

```
a = {'red'}
b = {'yellow'}
a.intersection(b)
```

leads to `set()`.
Is this a bug in `sympy`?

Answer (score 3):

The intersection cannot unambiguously give a result for objects which are variables. Your strings became Symbols with color names and `a` might equal `b` or it might not. If your elements were 'a+1' and 'a+2' the intersection would be an empty set because those two cannot be the same for finite values.

If you intend that distinct items are distinct, then map them to integers, allow simplification to take place, and then map them back to symbols:

```py
reps = {s:i for i, s in expr.atoms(Symbol)}
expr = expr.xreplace(reps).xreplace({i:s for s,i in reps.items()})
```

Comment: Alright! So my assumption of having a set of strings was wrong. Is there a possibility to have real string values in sympy sets?

Comment: No. All SymPy objects (should) contain SymPy objects. Why aren't you using a simple Python set?

Comment: Because I will have long expressions of unions and intersections of different sets and I wanted to use sympy's simplification methods to obtain shorter terms. I will also need a Universal set.

Comment: See addition to answer for suggestion to map symbols to ints.